# I get an error when I try to use the backend 'espeak' from the phonemizer package

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to convert text to phonemes with the phonemizer package

```py
from phonemizer import phonemize

text = ["Hello, world!", "Welcome to Medium!"]
phonemized = phonemize(text, language='en-us', backend='espeak')
print(phonemized)
```

but I keep getting this error

```
RuntimeError: espeak not installed on your system
```

I installed phonemizer in a new environment with anaconda prompt using pip install phonemizer.

```
(envthesis) C:\Users\Admin>phonemize --version phonemizer-3.2.1 available backends: segments-2.2.1 uninstalled backends: espeak, espeak-mbrola, festival
```

However, when I checked the espeak backend is not installed.

I also tried to install it on my windows, downloading the espeak dependence separately, but I still am not able to get it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the corent environment? I.e you installed the backends to your windows environment but are using the project one?

Comment: yes that could be the problem but actually I don't know how to import the espeak from windows to my current environment

Comment: you have to use `source venv/bin/activate` command in your terminal if you're on Mac, if you're on Windows use `source venv/Scripts/activate`, you should see a name of your env in front of your terminal input like so (venv), depending on the name of your environment

Comment: I'm not sure I really get what you mean. I tried to input the command as that (changing venv with my environment) in the terminal but it raises an error about 'source' as not recognized.

Comment: try just using ``.\venv\Scripts\activate``

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that putting these lines fixed that error (this is from https://bootphon.github.io/phonemizer/install.html):

from phonemizer.backend.espeak.wrapper import EspeakWrapper
EspeakWrapper.set_library('C:\Program Files\eSpeak NG\libespeak-ng.dll')

However, I now get the error
BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.

Answer (score -1):

I did some digging on this issue. It is caused because of how anaconda handles libs. You can try using python venv instead of anaconda to create the environment. I am also trying to find a working solution that will work in conda envs, will update here if I find any.